# close cmd after finishing the batch file using perl

Tags: perl, batch-file, mod-perl

I am not able to close the cmd window after finishing the batch file which I called from a perl script which will open a separate window for the batch file.
I am using the below code to accomplish this but it's not working for me.

```
 use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::Process;

my $cmd = "a.bat";

#system("start cmd.exe /k $cmd");

for (my $i=0;$i<1;$i++)
{
my $processObj;
Win32::Process::Create(
    $processObj,
    "C:/windows/system32/cmd.exe",
    "cmd.exe /k $cmd",
    0,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
    "."
);
#sleep(2);  # do other stuff
$processObj->GetExitCode(my $win32_exit_code);

while($win32_exit_code == Win32::Process::STILL_ACTIVE()) {
  sleep(1);
  $processObj->GetExitCode($win32_exit_code);
}

$processObj->Kill(0) or die "unable to kill $!";
}
```

can anyone help me to find where I am wrong or I am using wrong to do this ?

Comment: Can you change `/k` to `/c`?

Comment: Directly from the DOS Prompt: 
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then *terminates*

/K      Carries out the command specified by string but *remains*

Comment: Then, I think, Axeman's reply should be promoted to an answer.